# How can I add a file to a volume in a Docker image, using values from the docker-compose.yml?

Tags: docker, gradle, docker-compose

I have this .env file:

```
admin=admin
password=adminsPassword
stackName=integration-demo
```

the values of which are used in the docker-compose.yml file, like this:

```
    myService:
      build: 
        context: .
        dockerfile: myService.Dockerfile
        args:
          - instance=${stackName}.local
          - admin=${admin}
          - password=${password}
        volumes:
           - ./config:/config
```

I want to add them to the Docker compose file, like this:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine

ARG docker_properties_file=Username=$admin\nPassword=$password\nHost=$instance

RUN $docker_proprties_file >> config/gradle-docker.properties
```

so that I have a gradle-docker.properties file that looks like:

```
username=admin
password=adminsPassword
host=integration.demo.local
```

in the /config directory.

However, no gradle-docker.properties file is getting written.

How can I use the variable in a docker-compose.yml file to add data to a volume?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plain Docker and Docker Compose don’t have this capability.  You can create the file outside of Docker on the host and mount it into the container as you show, but neither Docker nor Compose has the templating capability you would need to be able to do this.

The overall approach you’re describing in the question builds a custom image for each set of configuration options.  That’s not really a best practice: imagine needing to recompile `ls` because you attached a USB drive you needed to look at.

One thing you can do in plain Docker is teach the image how to create its own configuration file at startup time.  You can do that with a script like, for example:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# I am docker-entrypoint.sh

# Create the config file
cat >config/gradle-docker.properties <<EOF
username=$USERNAME
et=$CETERA
EOF

# Run the main container process
exec "$@"
```

In your Dockerfile, `COPY` this file into the image and set it as the `ENTRYPOINT`; leave your `CMD` unchanged.  You must use the JSON-array form of the `ENTRYPOINT` directive.

```sh
...
COPY docker-entrypoint.sh .
RUN chmod +x docker-entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["./docker-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["java", "-jar", "application.jar"]
```

(In Kubernetes, the Helm package manager *does* have a templating system that can create content for a ConfigMap object that can be injected into a pod; but that’s a significant amount of extra machinery.)